# About wait() and waitpid()

Tags: c, wait, waitpid

So I wrote this code on C. I created a father, that has two child processes, and one becomes zombie. After one second it exits, and the father, that was waiting for him, finishes. The other child process remains orphan, and then finishes. My question is, what happens if I change the `wait` for `waitpid`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    pid_t pid;
    int status, value;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid > 0) { // Father

        pid = fork();

        if (pid > 0) { // Father
            wait(&status);
            value = WEXITSTATUS(status);

            if (value == 2)
                printf("Child 2");
            else if (value == 3)
                printf("Child 1");

        } else if (pid == 0) { //Child 2 - Orphan
            sleep(4);
            exit(2);

        } else {
            exit(1);
        }

    } else if (pid == 0) { // Child 1 - Zombie
        sleep(1);
        exit(3);

    } else {
        printf("Error al ejecutar el fork");
        exit(1);
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first child will become a zombie until the father exits, then it will become an orphan.

Comment: @Barmar But how is it possible? The first child (that becomes a zombie) also exits.

Comment: A process becomes an orphan if its parent exits without waiting for it. That's true even if the child has already exited. When it becomes an orphan, `init` adopts it, waits for it, and the process goes away.

Comment: @Barmar So, both child processes become orphan?

Comment: No. The process that you wait for with `waitpid()` doesn't become an orphan, because you wait for it.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting [wait/waitpid](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wait.html),

> The waitpid() function is provided for three reasons:
>
> - To support job control
> - To permit a non-blocking version of the wait() function
> - To permit a library routine, such as system() or pclose(), to wait for its children without interfering with other terminated children for which the process has not waited

and

> The waitpid() function shall be equivalent to wait() if the pid argument is (pid_t)-1 and the options argument is 0. Otherwise, its behavior shall be modified by the values of the pid and options arguments.

So the behavior of waitpid() depends on its arguments.

Comment: I'm guessing he means `waitpid(pid, &status);`.

Comment: @Ayak973 what is  a non-blocking version of the wait() function

Comment: @Mr.Kevin If you call `waitpid` with the `WNOHANG` option, it doesn't block.

Comment: @Barmar: If he writes what you suggested, the code doesn't compile (`waitpid()` takes three arguments).

Comment: Yeah, I was abbreviating to show the point I was making, that he's waiting for a specific pid